# Resizing iframe between two static-width panels - using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, resize

I have a setup with two side panels, one as float:left and one as float:right, and an iframe in between them. I want the two side panels to always have a width of 150px, and the iframe to fill the rest of the page. I am attempting to do this using jQuery to make functions that change the iframe width dynamically when the window is resized, yet it is not working. Here is what I have so far:

```
<body>

...

<script src="jquery.js">

        function setFrameSize() {
            $("#ifrm").width($(window).width() - $("#leftPanel").width() - $("#rightPanel").width());
        }

        $(window).resize(function() { setFrameSize(); });

        $(document).ready(function() { setFrameSize(); });

        </script>

...
</body>
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not working? Thanks!

Comment: As to why your javascript isn't working, it's possibly because you're not taking into consideration the borders the iframe might have. Iframes often have borders by default, and this would add to its total width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much better to do it with CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/7pbJb/

## HTML:

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="center"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

## CSS:

```
div{
    position:fixed;
    height:500px;}
#left{
    background:blue;
    left:0px;
    width:150px;
}
#center{
    background:green;
    right:150px;
    left:150px;
}
#right{
    background:orange;
    right:0px;
    width:150px;
}
```

Setting the left and right position of the center div causes it to stretch.

Comment: This is strangely not working for me, I think it is due to the nature of the iframe. it won't stretch to fill the space, how can I make this happen? Also, position absolute messes with my background image - how is that?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, you can go here:
http://home.comcast.net/~randomlyfunny/war/main.html

Comment: @theeggman85, Alright, just stick the iframe into a div setup the way I set mine up, and set the iframe's height and width to 100%.